# Using Express inside Atom Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I have an application running Express, and I am trying to distribute it using [electron](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-distribution.md).

Running electron in debug with this:

```
/path/to/electron/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron path-to-my-app
```

My application runs perfectly fine. Express fires up its server and everything works -- the main window opens correctly using `mainWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:3000/');`

When I follow the *distribution* tutorial (linked before) I copy my application resources to:

```
/path/to/electron/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app
```

But now when I run Electron.app, I see `Cannot GET /` in the main window... but I have no idea why.

Any ideas?

My only thought is that `process.cwd()` is not correctly helping me define the document root here:

```
//configure Express to default web requests to /workspace/ folder
expressApp.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/workspace'));
```

But if that's the case, I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example of electron app that uses mean stack? I would like to learn from that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that `express` for some reason didn't like my document root mapping.

Rather than using:

```
//configure Express to default web requests to /workspace/ folder
expressApp.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/workspace'));
```

I instead use this:

```
expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'workspace')));
```

Comment: You have posted this a few months ago, I'm interested to know if you still think that it's a viable option to use electron with expressjs?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `process.cwd`, use `process.resourcesPath` instead.

Comment: `process.cwd` was causing problems, but `resourcesPath` didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: You can use `app.getAppPath()` to get the app path no matter where your app is. Works both in development and production